# PHP contact form sending multiple emails when I add $headers

Tags: php, email, contacts, contact-form

I have a contact form which sends emails but displays my email server as the "from" and hence it is difficult to reply to emails sent from the contact form

I have tried adding

```
$headers = 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

to my script but although this works perfectly in respect to sending an email you can reply to, it still **also** sends an email which you cannot reply to!

I am a PHP newbie so I think I have made an error making two messages send, if someone could please point out what it is that would be much appreciated as although I have looked at other similar questions on here I cannot find a solution

Here is my code:

```
include ("includes/header.php");
$pagetitle   = "Contact Us";
$description = "";
$keywords    = "";
$name        = ($_POST['name']);
$email       = ($_POST['email']);
$message     = ($_POST['message']);
$from        = ($_POST['email']);
$to          = 'info@mydomain.co.uk'; 
$subject     = "Enquiry from Visitor " . $name;
$human       = ($_POST['human']);
$headers     = 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

<div class="container-fluid contactform">
   <div class="col-md-6 contactform-padding">   
     <h2>Contact Us</h2>

<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $human == '4') {              
      if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
         echo '<p>Thanks for getting in touch. Your message has been sent & We will get back to you shortly!</p>';
       } else { 
          echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
       }  
    } else if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $human != '4') {
       echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
?>

 <form method="post" action="index.php" data-ajax="false" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label " for="name">
   <p>Name</p>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
 </div>
```

Please could someone point out to me why this is sending two emails? I would REALLY appreciate it - I know I have made a stupid mistake and I cannot see why/how

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check code once again.

You are calling mail function two times.
One in above and another in *if condition*

from above code remove the **mail function**

mail can be sent from your if condition

Comment: Hey thanks for this, yes it is in the same file - it was in index but this took contact form to a blank page?

Comment: Sorry - the above code was in the same file where my contact form is

Comment: I did have the above code in index.php but it took my contact form to a blank page instead of the contact page with a "thank you" message on it

Comment: It takes me to the page with the thank you message at the top instead of the staying on the contact page!

Comment: Please use ajax.

Google : Ajax contact form

Comment: I have added rest of code to check for errors - I wanted to use this one as I spent a while making it if possible.. I am wondering if it has something to do with the second lot of PHP with the $human and error message? Please see my edited question

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was doing something like this, so if I just have the mail() in the if statement can I include the $headers there too? Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, you can \... just comment the first mail function and then execute your script. If you got your answer, please check this answer as solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This actually worked and it now sends one email which I can reply to. I didn't realise the mail function in an if statement actually sent an email as I am pretty new to this - Thanks again :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer but someone seems to have down-voted it! It was right though..